# How to stop automatic facebook login in my website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

i have a site which has a facebook login button. if i am logged in facebook on same browser, and clicks on website login button, it redirects me to the profile page without asking option to login via facebook or via form. i will add google plus button also in future.

so please tell me how to stop this automatic login in facebook.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about Browser Cookies and Cache.. The session already kept in your browser cache. so that's why .. It automatically redirects you to facebook. You need to clear your browser cache. to solve this issue...